# Stronger word for "selfish"

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

"Selfish" could mean anything from taking the last cookie to killing someone for the last cookie. Is there a harsher word for selfish that emphasises that it's wrong and/or hurtful?

Comment: If you're going to kill someone for the last cookie, I'd surmise that you are "sociopathic".

Comment: How about *cut-throat*?

Comment: Cookie-monstrous.

Comment: amoebionic, fascist - what's an antonym for selfish?

Comment: I'll throw in "parasitic," selfish at the expense of others.

Comment: @JonMarkPerry: altruistic

Comment: @Qaz Worth noting that a parasite relies on the host to survive. That's certainly not the case for cookies.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Synonyms like "egoistic", "egocentric", "self-centered" "self-loving", etc, are no stronger than selfish.  I would use an adverb before "selfish" lest its exact meaning be changed.  "Egocentric" and "self-centered" are not exactly the same as selfish.

**He is extremely/incredibly/profoundly/exceptionally/monstrously/etc selfish.**

Comment: Selfishness has connotations of both greed and pride (egotism), so if one wished to maintain that blend of meanings, using the modifying adverb is a good approach.

Answer (score 22):

[Egomaniacal](http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/egomaniacal):

> - overly concerned with one's own desires, needs, or interests
>
>   - a brilliant but egomaniacal urban planner who ruthlessly sought to impose his vision of the ideal cityscape (M-W)

Answer (score 12):

[Avaricious](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/avaricious) denotes a kind of selfishness that knows no limits.

From the link:

> **avaricious** | *adjective* | av·a·ri·cious | \ˌa-və-ˈri-shəs\
>
> - greedy of gain; excessively acquisitive especially in seeking to hoard riches
>
> > *an avaricious scheme to con the elderly couple out of thousands of dollars*

Comment: My impression is that avaricious has more to do with the greed for material and wealth rather than the type of egocentricity that is characteristic of excessively selfish people.

Comment: @MichaelLai You are correct, but "selfish" and "avaricious" are probably only 1 step away from each other in a thesaurus. Also, the questioner posed the question in the context of material greed, making this an apt choice.

Answer (score 5):

I respectfully disagree that an adverb is the ideal route. English is the richest lexicon that has ever existed: you have an arsenal of words from which to choose the ideal way to fillet your subject.

Your question is short, but you asked for a word that conveys two meanings: selfishness, and that the selfishness is "wrong." I will interpret that as morally wrong.

1. We say people are **inconsiderate** when they are selfish in a
   situation when it is wrong to be selfish.
2. **Self-seeking** and **self-serving** both connote selfishness that is wrong.
3. In specific situations, such as the case of the cookie caper, narrower words are fantastic: **gluttonous** and **greedy** are so wrong that Christians list them as two of the [seven worst sins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven_deadly_sins).
4. **Stingy** and **parsimonious** are clearly wrong, but the selfish aspect is not as strongly present as some of the other words.

Which do you feel has more punch?

> He ate all of the cookies again. He is extremely selfish.

or

> All the cookies are gone. That gluttonous pig.

Whether you want a broad word or a narrow term, there is almost certainly something more provocative than "extremely."

Comment: -1: English is *not* the richest lexicon ever to have existed; quite the opposite: it is notorious for its relative lack of range and precision when compared to many other languages. This is the point being touched on when, for example, adult learners of English complain that they can't adequately express their feelings because English speakers use the same word ("love") to describe how they feel about an old friend, how they feel about their spouse, and how they feel about a cheeseburger.

Comment: @MatthewNajmon I double your words. English is my second language (being Portuguese my first one), and is almost impossible for me readily translate a big text from Portuguese to English without _massive_ losses in meaning or ridiculously increase in the word count.

Comment: No language is comprehensive. Neruda could only have written in Spanish. Confucius could not have taught in any Indo-European language. There are different ways to count lexemes, but the _Cambridge Encyclopedia of the English Language_ says English has 500,000 lexemes, French 187k(?), Spanish 135k(?), and all others much fewer. If it is "notorious," what are your cites? English is not comprehensive, but it is more versatile and rich than any other language. Furthermore, **downvoting an answer because you disagree with a minor point is petty** and misses the point of having a voting system.

Comment: @HunterHogan I agree with your bold words, but not fully about lexemes. English has, in very many cases, two different lexemes that mean exactly the same; one originating from a Germanic language, the other from a Romanic language (mostly Latin/French). This effectively doubles the required lexemes for the same amount of expressionism. The greater morphism of Romanic languages reduces the required lexemes even further. And then, at least in German, Lehnworte and Fremdworte are not counted towards the lexeme count, while they clearly are in English...

Comment: +1 for not using adverbs. I have no idea why people are hating on this answer based on a line I'm sure was not meant to hurt anyone. Whether English has or doesn't have the richest lexicon is not very relevant here.

Comment: I agree. Right now, my answer has eight upvotes and three downvotes. The original question was broad and vague and I offered a range of options. Another answer offered "single-minded," and probably deserves the six downvotes it has. My answer is on topic and sufficiently explained. Haters on EL&U make me think that we will soon read about nuns rioting, burning tires, and flipping-over cars. Tomorrow's headline: **Extremely Audacious Adverbs Inadvertently Cause Profoundly Raucous Rampage**

Answer (score 2):

*Exploitative*.

One wants his/her own profit at others' cost. He/she does not care about others.

Answer (score 2):

If you're really looking for a word that means "would kill for a cookie", then I think you need something a bit stronger than what I see suggested so far. Suggestions include: psychopathic, psychotic, psycho, homicidal, maniac, murderous, deranged, unhinged, demented, narcissistic, megalomaniacal.

Comment: totally narcissistic and/or megalomanical

Answer (score 1):

The term *[stingy](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/stingy)* has a fairly negative connotation

> Unwilling to give or spend; ungenerous:
>
> *his employer is stingy and idle*
>
> *he was stingy with his information*

*Oxford Dictionaries Online*

The term *[niggardly](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/niggardly)* is very pejorative

> grudgingly mean about spending or granting: begrudging

*Merriam-Webster*

However it is rarely used, most likely because it is so similar sounding to a racial epithet. See this usage note from *[Oxford Dictionaries Online](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/niggard#niggard__9)*

> The words niggard and niggardly have no connection with the highly offensive term nigger, but because of the similarity of sound and its negative meaning of ‘mean, ungenerous,’ many people are uncomfortable with using it for fear of causing offense, and in the US it is now widely avoided.

Answer (score 1):

*Self-obsessed* carries implications that the subject thinks of little else besides himself. For an intensifying adverb, I would try *pathologically* self-obsessed.

Answer (score -5):

Not a quite a synonym for selfish, but, based on your example, *unscrupulous* might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score -6):

single-minded can be deceptively stronger than selfish.

Comment: "being single-minded is not evocative of being selfish.

Comment: I am single-mindedly devoted to charitable causes... so I guess that would make me selfishly selfless, or something?